# How to update records from an index list rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to update a user's status from a long list of user by clicking a "make user" button which will update the user's "status" from 'admin' to 'user'. However, the code I am using only updates the first user from 'admin' to 'user', no matter which button i press.

I believe the error is in the controller, in the first line of update.

How can I make the update function select the record that i clicked "make user" and update that, instead of the first record listed? Thanks!

controller

```
def index
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
def update
    @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(update_user_params)
    redirect_to '/dashboard/users'
end
```

the problem must be in the (params[:id]).
Form code

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
              <tr id="dashfield">
                <td><%= user.first_name%></td>
                <td><%= user.last_name %></td>
                <td><%= user.email %></td>
                <td><%= user.role %></td>
                <td><%= form_for user, method: :put do |f|%>
                      <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => 'user'%>
                      <%= f.submit 'Make User'%>
                  <%end%><%= form_for user, method: :put do |f|%>
                      <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => 'admin'%>
                      <%= f.submit 'Make Admin'%>
                  <%end%></td>
              </tr>
          <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that @hour is exists or not, then you can update

```
def update
    @user = User.find_by(params[:id]) if params[:id].present?
    if @hour.present?
     @user.update_attributes(update_user_params)
     redirect_to '/dashboard/users'
    end
 end
```

You have to check all possible failure first.

**Edit:**
you can set user id like: `<%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => user.id %>`

Comment: How could i make the form function for only the record it is on? because it still only edits the first record in the database

Comment: sorry, i posted the wrong controller but it is the same thing, with different labels

Comment: In your form you need to set the user id with hidden field. I saw your form but there is no user id defined.

Comment: yes, but in your form you need to print the id with hidden form, and also send it to controller. Because your controller doesn't know which your info it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87067/discussion-between-sirajus-salayhin-and-d-kucher).